# Files missing on Source Control Panel

Tags: visual-studio-code

I'm using VSCode V139.2 and on a single project, I'm not seeing 
files on the source control panel.

I thought about installing another version, but then opened another folder and the changes appear on that project.

Is that a configuration toggle that I'm missing here?

[image]

Answer (score 0):

Found it, command palette, Source Control: Focus on xxx view